# how to run wamp server in c#

Tags: c#, wamp

How do I do this? Can this be done through code in C# ? I use this code to do this but it doesn't work .

```
    using System;
    using System.Diagnostics;

    namespace ConsoleApp1
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                Process.Start(@"C:\wamp64\wampmanager.exe");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: No. You can't do like this. WAMP is not a process which you are trying to initiate.

Comment: @SureshKamrushi What can I do to run this program?
I need to run this program immediately after I open my program
What can I do?

Comment: please see thsi link: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ade83b46-1ddc-430c-900b-f67211c927e7/how-to-open-wamp-server?forum=vbgeneral

Comment: @AminGolmahalle Unfortunately I couldn't execute!
Have you tried this method before ?! Are you sure?
Can you post an example code here?

Comment: I am not sure that this is possible.

Comment: @SureshKamrushi please help me !